# Como hacer Auditoria Django

Tags: django

Buenas noches estoy realizando mi App en Django y estoy necesitando crear un log de auditoría donde pueda registrar si crearon/modificaron/eliminaron un registro, que usuario lo hizo y fecha del registro.

Agardezco sugerencias para poder implementar esta funcionalidad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hay varias formas y depende mucho de cual es tu objetivo y como quieras implementarlo:

1. Implementar una clase abstracta para auditoría:

   > Puedes escribir una clase abstracta que tenga tus campos de auditoría, y la tabla se creará automáticamente con esos campos, eso si.

---

```
class AudtoriaMixin(models.Model):
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    created_by = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, editable=False)
    modified_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    modified_by = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, editable=False)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

---

```
class Usuario(AudtoriaMixin):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

---

2. Crear un signal que capture los eventos de guardado y eliminado y los vaya registrando en una tabla.

   > La ventaja de usar esta forma es que no es intrusiva, no hay que modificar los modelos para usarla, la desventaja es que no puedes personalizar algunos parámetros extra, como el usuario que está modificando.

---

```
@receiver(post_save)
def audit(sender, **kwargs):
    obj_str = str(kwargs.get('instance'))
    Auditoria(instancia = obj_str, accion="guardado").save()
```

---

3. Usar un campo `AuditTrail`:

   > Puedes copiar el snippet desde https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/AuditTrail y usarlo para guardar un campo de auditoría para cualquier modelo.

---

```
from django.db import models
import audit

class Usuario(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    salary = models.PositiveIntegerField()

    history = audit.AuditTrail()
```

---

4. Usar una librería externa para auditar y guardar historial:

   > Por último puedes usar cualquiera de las aplicaciones que brinda el universo de django packages: https://djangopackages.org/grids/g/model-audit/

Answer (score -1):

He usado [simple history](https://django-simple-history.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) en un par de proyectos y ha funcionado muy bien.  Se encarga de crear una copia de la tabla o modelo sobre el que se quiere tener registro.

La instalación es trivial y la creación de las tablas nuevas sólo requiere de una línea en el `models.py`.

Comment: Esto es mas un comentario que una respuesta. Por favor revisa el centro de ayuda https://es.stackoverflow.com/help

Comment: @Xerif A decir verdad, no veo en dónde está el problema.  Si me puedes guiar un poco mejor sobre el punto en específico que no estoy abordando, te lo agradecería.  Del mismo modo, quien pregunta no está haciendo una pregunta puntual y agradece sugerencias, la cual estoy haciendo.  Saludos.

Comment: Fijate en la respuesta de @Ali es concisa y con ejemplos.  Proporciona y postea una solución y una explicación. En tu respuesta solo aportas una opinión. Es preferible opinar en los comentarios.